# Download and play video

Tags: plugin, flash

How is it possible to download and play videos from any websites? The earlier version 5.5.5 had such option. where one can use such feature (for videos without a download option or a sign in for download) to download any video. but once it got upgraded to 6. any video is playing.

Answer (score 1):

[image: "reenable spacebar heating"]

The latest Tor Browser update enabled the MediaSource video playing, this was set as default in Firefox 42.0, and thus when Tor Browser upgraded from 38 ESR to 45 ESR in 6.0 this change came into effect.

Tickets [#19200](https://bugs.torproject.org/19200) and [#19210](https://bugs.torproject.org/19210) cover this new functionality, mostly in that previously high security level ensured that click-to-play was required before any media played.

This is intended functionality. You may want to consider using a tool like [`youtube-dl`](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) as documented on the Tails FAQ: ["Can I download videos from websites?"](https://tails.boum.org/support/faq/index.en.html#index31h2)